# PHP Json_encode not working with object while JsonSerializable is implemented

Tags: php, json

I've got a problem. I got 2 PHP files that each echo a `json_encode()` of an array with objects (one an array of users and one an array of rewards). However rewards works perfectly fine while users returns `[{},{},{}]`

here's my **users.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require('../logic/User.php');
require('../database/Database.php');

$database = new Database();

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $user = $database->getUserById($_GET['id']);
    if($user != false){
        echo json_encode($user);
    }else{
        echo 'User not found';
    }
}else {
    $users = $database->getUsers();
    echo json_encode($users);
}
?>
```

And here's my **User** class (without magic methods):

```
class User implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $birthday;
    private $gender;
    private $address;
    private $postalcode;
    private $phonenr;
    private $email;
    private $facebookid;

    private $accessible = array('id', 'name', 'birthday', 'gender', 'address', 'postalcode', 'phonenr', 'email', 'facebookid');
    private $editable = array('name', 'birthday', 'gender', 'address', 'postalcode', 'phonenr', 'email', 'facebookid');
    private $required = array('id', 'name');

//getter, setter, constructor

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return ['id' => $this->id,
            'name'=>$this->name,
            'birthday'=>$this->birthday,
            'gender'=>$this->gender,
            'address'=>$this->address,
            'postalcode'=>$this->postalcode,
            'phonenr'=>$this->phonenr,
            'email'=>$this->email,
            'facebookid'=>$this->facebookid
        ];
    }
}
```

**$users** is filled, so the problems must be the `json_encode()`

Comment: what should returns?

Comment: What are the types of private properties? If some of your properties are objects they should also implement `JsonSerializable`.

Comment: the properties are all strings, ints or dates (which I believe is just a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the user properties are private.
If you make them public they will show.

However, decide if it you want to change them to public because they are probably private for a reason.